# Import a date from CSV to Date field

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm working on a Druapl 8 project and I'm trying to execute a migration which serve to import content of a basic content type, the content type has a field of type Date and the associated field in my CSV source file has the format "dd-mm-yyyy", I used the 'format_date' plugin to migrate the date as bellow:

```
process:
  field_date:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'd-m-Y'
    to_format: 'd/m/Y'
    source: Date
```

with `field_date` is the machine name of my content type date field, and Date is the field name in my csv file:
source.csv

```
title,Date
title 1,12-01-2017
title 2,13-03-2018
```

After migration the content has been created as it should but with date value as bellow: 
[image]

Any help please!

Comment: Let try replace **to_format: 'd/m/Y'** to **to_format: 'Y-m-d'**.

Comment: Ok, let me write an answer and explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert source date from **d-m-Y** to **Y-m-d**

```
process:
  field_date:
    plugin: format_date
    from_format: 'd-m-Y'
    to_format: 'Y-m-d'
    source: Date
```

because default field Date use format [**Y-m-d**](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/datetime/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/DateTimeItemInterface.php#n23) to store date. and [**Y-m-d\TH:i:s**](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/datetime/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/DateTimeItemInterface.php#n18) to store datatime.

Form display just show default pattern (mm-dd-yyyy) of html5 input [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: Yeah, the migrate plugins are a bit generic for source/destination, and the `format_date` plugin doesn't assume a datetime destination, just something that needs a formatted date.