# How do I migrate the "Created" and "Modified" date fields?

Tags: nodes, migrations

I created a migration script to test this out.

This is the code I used.

```
id: article_csv_import
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: Import articles
label: 'Import articles'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'modules/custom/sigtarp_migrate/data/articles.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - id
process:
  nid: id
  title: title
  body/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
  body/value: body
  changed:
    plugin: callback
    source: update
    callable: strtotime
    created: date
  created:
    plugin: callback
    source: update
    callable: strtotime
    created: DateCreated
  status: Status
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: article
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
```

When I run the migration script, this is what happen when both the *Changed* and *Created* fields are entered.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

This is the content of the CSV file used for the migration.

> [image: screenshot]

Why is the date off? How can I fix it?

Comment: May have todo with timezone, can you show what your csv looks like when opened on Notepad? Want to make sure your Excel isn't hidding things.

Comment: Here here what it look like in my csv

Comment: id,title,body ,DateCreated,update,Status
1,title 1,some body text 1 ,4/3/1994,4/3/1994,1
2,title 2,some body text 2 ,4/13/1996,4/13/1996,1
3,title 3,some body text 3,9/25/2003,9/25/2003,1

Comment: instead of the plugin: callback

Comment: from_format: 'm/d/Y'

Comment: So what is to_format: ''

Comment: did not work I becaue you the lead year

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that for created & changed dates, they are stored [differently than field_date's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/269350/27710), you must convert these to Unix universal time.

```
  changed:
    plugin: format_date
    source: update
    from_format: 'm/d/Y'
    to_format: 'U'
    from_timezone: 'UTC'
    to_timezone: 'UTC'
  created:
    plugin: format_date
    source: DateCreated
    from_format: 'm/d/Y'
    to_format: 'U'
    from_timezone: 'UTC'
    to_timezone: 'UTC'
```

Comment: Thanks you so much